# Multiple databases in Mobile Servvies Azure for IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, azure, ios7

I am trying to load one database to get an ID, then with that ID opening another database and retrieving an URL.

Do I first of all

1. Open the database connection with the azure URL and my key
2. Retrieve the ID from the first database and store it.
3. Open the 2nd database and use NSPRedicure on that one to query it with the ID from my first database.
4. Store all the urls from that database in an array.

Would that be the best way ? I am looking at the easiest way and at the moment thats the only way I can think of doing it.